# "Walking" buffer in C

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I'm not sure if this approach is correct in C (in detail avrgcc for Atmel xmega). The data are ASCII strings.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64
char dataBuffer[2 * BUFFER_SIZE];
char pageBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void addLine(char *line) {
    strcat(dataBuffer, line);
    if (strlen(dataBuffer) > BUFFER_SIZE) {
        strncpy(pageBuffer, dataBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        // <----
        dataBuffer = &dataBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        // ---->
    }
    // do something other
}
```

The goal is to copy exactly `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes from `dataBuffer` to `pageBuffer` and to leave the remaining bytes in the first one.

I'm afraid about memory. Initially the compiler allocates 2 * `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes at an address. But what happens when I change the pointer of the first location? I bet I cannot go beyond the original boundaries of the array.

The only other approach I know is the circular buffer, but this imply to use begin and end pointers and I cannot use the string functions (due to the wrap around). Not a big matter... but I want to follow this way only if I need to.

### EDIT

Because it seems I didn't explained well my goal I try to repeat it in different words.

Let's say you want to program a page in a flash memory. The page has a size of `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes. You receive some data of different lengths (though shorter than `BUFFER_SIZE`). So you want to store the received data (`dataBuffer`) until you reach the size of the page.

At this point you want to move out the first `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes to the `pageBuffer` which is the array to be stored into the memory. Then you want to continue to concatenate the new received strings until you reach again the page size and restart.

This code seems to work:

```
#define PAGE_SIZE       256

char lineBuffer[2 * PAGE_SIZE + 1];
char pageBuffer[PAGE_SIZE + 1];

void appendLine(char *line) {
    strcat(lineBuffer, line);
    if (strlen(lineBuffer) > PAGE_SIZE) {
        strncpy(pageBuffer, lineBuffer, PAGE_SIZE);
        char foo[PAGE_SIZE + 1];
        strcpy(foo, lineBuffer + PAGE_SIZE);
        strcpy(lineBuffer, foo);
        // use pageBuffer
        strcpy(pageBuffer, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also thinking about this: `strcpy(dataBuffer, dataBuffer + BUFFER_SIZE);`

Comment: Does this compile? I guess it does not.

Comment: Yes, I've just left out the headers and the main() because I'm talking about a microcontroller. But the function is exactly the same I'm using. Why it should not compile?

Comment: As I write in my answer: `dataBuffer = &dataBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` is invalid and can't compile

Comment: Your bet is lost. YOu **shall** not go beyond the boundaries. C does not prevent you from shooting your foot, hand or head. You should state what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Olaf - Not sure what you are referring to - is it the `strcat`?

Comment: @4386427 you're right. I've actually did copy & paste from my code. But after the last modification and before to compile again. You're right of course. The difference was dataBuffer was a pointer not the array itself! I apologize.

Comment: @4386427: My comment was very clear in the context of the question. What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @Olaf I wrote my "goal" into the question. I need to move `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes from `dataBuffer` to `pageBuffer` when I have more than `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes. The remaining ones should be placed at the beginning of `dataBuffer` in order to go ahead... if it's still not clear, please ask more!

Comment: @Olaf - I'm not sure where you see that the code `go beyond the boundaries` - please point to the specific code.

Comment: @Mark - from your comment it seems that my answer gives you just what you are looking for.

Comment: @4386427: Not reasonable without a [mcve]. There is not all code shown, not enough information what OP wants to accomplish. Just that: 1) If arrays were pointers, they would be called "pointers", not "arrays". 2) **buffers** are typically not well suited for the string functions. But without more info, even the latter is not certain. About the bet, how about reading the question text carefully?

Comment: @4386427: The bet might be badly worded. I read as if the implemention will ensure this. OP might ask if his code goes beyond the limits. Didn't verify that one.

Comment: I apologize if my English is not so good. My code DOES go outside the boundaries because my (wrong) approach was to change the pointer from the first element of the array to the first one + `BUFFER_SIZE`. After two iterations I'm out of its size.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve but the posted code can't compile.

Changing the value of `dataBuffer` is **not** allowed, i.e. this is illegal:

```
dataBuffer = &dataBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

// Compile error: assignment to expression with array type
```

I think you should use `memcpy` instead. Like:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64
char dataBuffer[2 * BUFFER_SIZE];
char pageBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void addLine(char *line) {
    strcat(dataBuffer, line);
    if (strlen(dataBuffer) > BUFFER_SIZE) {
        memcpy(pageBuffer, dataBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        // <----
        memcpy(dataBuffer, dataBuffer + BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);
        // ---->
    }
    // do something other
}
```

Besides that you should check for buffer overflow before doing the `strcat`

Like:

```
if (strlen(dataBuffer) + strlen(dataBuffer) >= BUFFER_SIZE)
{
    // Error handling
}
```